# How to test if video is local or stream?

Tags: applescript, quicktime

If I watch a video in **QuickTime Player**, how I can test in my **AppleScript**, if this video file is on my Mac or is it streamed live from the net?

Comment: Disable the WiFi :)

Answer (score 1):

If you open AppleScript editor and then open dictionary and choose your version of quicktime player, you can see the dictionary your system supports.

On Mountain Lion - you would look under the Standard Suite and inspect the document property to see that file would tell you if the movie is saved locally.

Presumably, you could then infer that you are playing HTTP or RSTP streaming video, but I don't see any way for AppleScript (or automator) to know if the stream was previously recorded or live from the dictionary Apple provides for the version 10.2 of Quicktime Player.

[image]